# How to remove comments from properties file using maven build?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, properties-file

Suppose I have following in my properties file

```
#production db
db.url=com.some.prod.url
db.port=4565

#development db
#db.url=com.some.dev.url
#db.port=4577
```

After the build finishes, I want my properties file clean of all commented properties in the build file. So, final outcome becomes:

```
db.url=com.some.prod.url
db.port=4565
```

Comment: And what is the problem with comments in property files?

Comment: don't want to expose production related properties on dev/qa servers & vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out finally.
Used `maven-replacer-plugin`, and replaced a regex of `<new line><hash><any set of characters>` i.e. `\r\n#(.*)` with `<blank>`

**Update**: in order to be able to execute this on jenkins(linux instance, in my case), have added a pattern `\n#(.*)`

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>target/**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <commentsEnabled>false</commentsEnabled>
                <regex>true</regex>
                <replacements>
                    <replacement>
                        <token>\r\n#(.*)</token>
                        <value></value>
                    </replacement>
                    <!-- Following line was added in update(linux compatible) -->
                    <replacement>
                        <token>\n#(.*)</token>
                        <value></value>
                    </replacement>
                </replacements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Maven Antrun Plugin and ant task [replaceregexp](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html)

Comment: let me check & get back